# Is there an easy way to set up HTTP Basic Authentication for a Meteor app?

Tags: basic-authentication, meteor

I have a simple Meteor application demo which I'd like to deploy, but I'd like it to be password protected. No need for individual user account -- a single login / pword is sufficient for now.

Any advice? I realize Meteor has an auth branch under active development, and so a full featured solution will be available before long. But if anyone can advise a path of least resistance for the short term, I'd be grateful.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible if u write a little piece of connect middleware and then slip it into the beginning of the stack. Try using this:-

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    var require = __meteor_bootstrap__.require;
    var connect = require('connect');

    __meteor_bootstrap__.app.stack.splice(0, 0, {
      route: '',
      handle: connect.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
        return 'guest' == user & 'password' == pass;
      })
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: FYI - I also added a basic-auth package to [Github](https://github.com/Jabbslad/basic-auth) and [Atmosphere](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/), feel free to use and/or enhance.

Comment: As of Meteor 0.6.0 `__meteor_bootstrap__.require();` is replaced with `Npm.require();`

Answer (score 2):

I had to adjust @Jabbslad code a little bit to make it working with 0.6.5 :

```
if (Meteor.is_server) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    WebApp.connectHandlers.stack.splice(0, 0, {
      route: '',
      handle: WebApp.__basicAuth__(function(user, pass){
        return 'guest' == user & 'password' == pass;
      })
    });
  });
}
```

I didn't like replacing `connect.basicAuth` with `WebApp.__basicAuth__`, but `Npm.require("connect")` is throwing errors in Meteor 0.6.5, and I can't find the reason why.